# C++ Copy Map to Vector Templated

Tags: c++

I have the following:

```
template<typename MapT>
std::vector<int> mapToVec(const MapT &_map) {
   std::vector<int> values;
   for(const auto &entry : _map)
   {
      values.push_back(entry.second);
   }
   return values;
}
```

Obviously this only works if the value type of the map is an int. How do I template this further to convert a map to a vector of it's value type?

So essentially it should return a vector of the values (or second elements of the key-value pairs) of any std::map passed in.

Comment: The value type of vector should be `map::mapped_type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `typename MapT::mapped_type` as the `std::vector::value_type`, eg:

```
template<typename MapT>
std::vector<typename MapT::mapped_type> mapToVec(const MapT &_map)
{
   std::vector<typename MapT::mapped_type> values;
   values.reserve(_map.size());
   for(const auto &entry : _map)
   {
      values.push_back(entry.second);
   }
   return values;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/lOflLr)

Alternatively, you can share a template argument for both the `std::vector::value_type` and the `std::map::mapped_type`, eg:

```
template<typename KeyT, typename ValueT>
std::vector<ValueT> mapToVec(const std::map<KeyT, ValueT> &_map)
{
   std::vector<ValueT> values;
   values.reserve(_map.size());
   for(const auto &entry : _map)
   {
      values.push_back(entry.second);
   }
   return values;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/qMKJxA)

Comment: Both work, the second method seems to better imply that the argument is indeed an std::map.

Answer (score 0):

In C++23, you can combine [`views::keys`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/keys_view) with [`ranges::to`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/range.utility.conv.to)

```
template<typename MapT>
auto mapToVec(const MapT &_map) {
  return _map | std::views::values | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eKW4GTosh)